# Use MS-Access Combobox over and over without mouse

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I'm using a combobox to append text in an unbound textbox. I click the dropdown arrow and either start typing (autoexpanding, which is the real reason/use-case for the combobox) or clicking a selection. I may want to do this 2 or 3 more times. I'd rather not have to click the dropdown again. I just want to start typing. The last 2 lines here are not doing it for me:

```vbs
Private Sub cmboTag1_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txtTags.Value = Me.txtTags.Value & " " & Me.cmboTag1.Value
    Me.cmboTag1.SetFocus
    Me.cmboTag1.Dropdown
End Sub
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a strong aversion to `SendKeys` (and some people do) then this seems to work for me:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim cmboUpdated As Boolean

Private Sub cmboTag1_AfterUpdate()
    cmboUpdated = True
    Me.txtTags.Value = Me.txtTags.Value & " " & Me.cmboTag1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub cmboTag1_GotFocus()
    cmboUpdated = False
    SendKeys "%{DOWN}"
End Sub

Private Sub cmboTag1_LostFocus()
    If cmboUpdated Then
        SendKeys "+{TAB}"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Been so long I had to look up key bindings: % is ALT, + is SHIFT, ^ is CTRL, etc... First decent use of SendKeys I have seen.

Comment: Please note that sendkeys may not work in some windows versions.